Coveo Atomic React Wrapper - how to set placeholder text on search box?
We are using @coveo/atomic-react 1.2.2. The react wrapper is required as the non-react elements are not compatible with our NodeJS solution.
We need to be able to change the placeholder text on the AtomicSearchBox. In all locations it defaults to say "Search" and adding the placeholder attribute does not do anything. How can I change the placeholder text?
<AtomicSearchBox placeholder="Search by location name or zipcode">
    <AtomicSearchBoxQuerySuggestions maxWithQuery={5} />
    <AtomicSearchBoxRecentQueries maxWithQuery={5} />
</AtomicSearchBox>


The solution is to set localization on the wrapping AtomicSearchInterface:
<AtomicSearchInterface
        engine={searchEngine}
        language="en"
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        localization={(i18n: any) => {
          i18n.addResourceBundle('en', 'translation', {
            search: 'Custom Search Placeholder',
          });
        }}
      >

note that for Typescript, I had to disable eslint on the localization line to allow i18n to be type any
